# Using other layout element in another activity

Tags: android

i m new to android and working on the gridview onitemclicklistener and want to get the other layout element in the activity class because gridview is implement in the activity class which having its own layout xml file and the gridview item are having the different layout xml file which we are inflating in the adapter class. i had already tried with the setTag in one java class file and getTag in the another java class file.

putting some code for the acitvity class [Here](http://pastebin.com/UEusBG8k)

putting the adapter class code [here](http://pastebin.com/ts3tyVra)

putting the xml file for the gridview [here](http://pastebin.com/rzXvCtBD)

now the gridview item layout xml where we have the imagebutton and that we need in the acitvity class [here](http://pastebin.com/gythq0xL)

the two xml i had put is used in the different java class file.

so now the question is

how can we get the imagebutton as you will found with name as **tuaky_select_imagebutt** in the activity class gridview on itemclicklistener so i can perform some action on that imagebutton also.

i followed this [link](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) for the setTag and getTag of the xml item.

Comment: Use this tag in xml file <include
        android:id="`enter code here`@+id/include_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/your_comman_layout" />

Answer (score 0):

We can't achieve  through setTag and getTag but do the operation of specified xml file element 
where we are inflating the layout so that we easily can access that element of xml file and perform some operation on it.